# frequent pod rotation in eks cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-ec2, elastic-container-registry

I have 4 replicas(pods) of my service deployed in eks cluster. The pods are getting rotated more frequently than expected. One pod is getting killed and in few seconds another pod is getting created but in between there is a delay of 10-15 seconds and the requests received by pod that is being killed are throwing 502 or 504 errors. cpu utilisation and memory utilisation and throughtput are normal at the time instance when this is happening.

What other things need to be checked and verified to debug the reason and what could be the possible solution for this?

I have tried changing the pods from liveness to readiness so that they only serve the traffic when they are healthy. Tried increasing the termination grace period to 5 minutes but neither of these worked.
The minimum replicas set in the config file is 4.

Comment: can you post the deployment.yaml?

Comment: What do the pod events say is the reason for the restart? Can you show the event part of `describe` on the pod?

Comment: What is the reason for the pods restart? Can you show `logs` and event part of `describe pod` ?